# SQLite error. My query throws an error saying a column does not exist

Tags: sqlite

My app runs a query to the local sqlite database which looks the following:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  td.* FROM TAGDATA td INNER JOIN (SELECT tag_id, MAX(created_at)" +
                " AS maxtime FROM TAGDATA GROUP BY tag_id) groupedtd ON td.tag_id = groupedtd.tag_id" +
                " AND td.created_at = groupedtd.maxtime order by td.tag_id";
```

I get an error on this query stating that "created_at" does not exist even though the app runs perfectly on another 2 phones. Is this a phone specific error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself after some time.
The app still had a remnant of an old database schema stored on Android.
Uninstalled the app and reinstalling fixed the error.